# What that statement means in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

```
[](auto e) { return islower(e) ;}
```

I am a begineer in c++, can someone explain me what is the meaning of that statement in c++

Comment: It’s a lambda expression. It’s basically a function.

Comment: They are called lambda functions : (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/) and they are quite useful. E.g. for use in standard library algorithms like std::find_if, and when passing functions to other threads.